# Cursor in new project is selecting attached geometry, not one face or edge?

Tags: rendering, faces, geometry, extrude, mouse

I've been working with Blender for about a year now, teaching myself how to 3d model etc. I've never had any issues with the mouse until today, when i opened a new project and started.

The cursor seems to be stuck in a mode where it will only select the object + the surrounding geometry. It doesnt seem to matter if im in face/vertice/edge mode...it acts like its huge and its nearly impossible to manipulate my model this way.

The only difference i did in this project was select the add-on for "Images as planes". I feel like i might have activated a hotkey or misclicked an icon or something XD (Its acting like i hit c but i did not...and i cant get the cursor to make a box the normal way, it looks like the c circle)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have you enabled the Proportional Editing option?

Comment: I could see why you'd ask that but no, the icon for that is inactive. Toggling it did not change the issue :(

Comment: maybe show a screenshot of your full Blender interface? Or even share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/192878dab87e44bcb71861d614a42eba

Comment: Can't reproduce the error in the file. Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that you have the *Select Circle* selected, it will be your default select tool. Choose *Tweak* instead. You can also switch with the <kbd>W</kbd> shortcut.

[image]